# About rails polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models , Article, User, Approval. and this is the Approval table

```
def change
  create_table :approvals do |t|
    t.references :user, foreign_key: true
    t.references :approvable, polymorphic: true

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

this is  the three models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :approvals    
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :approvals, as: :approvable
end


class Approval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :approvable, polymorphic: true
end
```

now i want to show an approval image in the article show page, and it's diffenrence according if the current_user has approved the article, i think there is a very eazy way to do this, but i can only come up with a stupid way to
do this, like :

```
<% @article.approvals.each do |approval| %>
   <% if approval.user_id == current_user.id %>
     # show has approvaled image
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

i think it maybe inefficient, please tell me a better solution, Thanks! : )

maybe i didn't express very well, i mean the approval is praise  or like?

Answer (score 0):

You can first check for approvals which belongs to current_user and article.

So in `controller` method use(considering you have only one article at a time),

```
@current_user_approvals = Approval.where(user_id: current_user.id, article_id: @article.id)
```

and then use `@current_user_approvals in view` as,

```
<% @current_user_approvals.each do |approval| %>
   # show has approval image
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphic should not be used in this case. you can use has_many :through to achieve approval. read the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

the migration would be:

```
class CreateApprovals < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :approvals do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :article
    end
  end
end
```

models would be like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :approvals
  has_many :approved_articles, through: :approvals, source: :article
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :approvals
  has_many :approved_users, through: :approvals, source: :user
end

class Approval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Now we can do the tricks (in rails console):

```
# create a user
user = User.create(name: 'user')
# create an article
article = user.articles.create(name: 'article')

# check whether article is approved
user.approved_articles.include?(article) # => false
# approve the article
user.approved_articles << article
# check check whether article is approved again
user.approved_articles.include?(article) # => true
```

---

edited version, since we do want to use polymorphic on approvals. the key is to use source_type to specify the polymorphic type (in this case it's 'Article')

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :approvals
  has_many :approved_articles, through: :approvals, source: :approvable, source_type: 'Article'
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :approvals, as: :approvable
  has_many :approved_users, through: :approvals, source: :user
end

class Approval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :approvable, polymorphic: true
end
```

tests above in console still work.

Comment: yeah, in my whole project there are many models has approval, I just didnt't show the total code，i had thouht about `include?(article)` method, but i don't know how it would be when i use polymorphic.

Comment: @Dearest it makes sense to use polymorphic on approvals. i've updated the answer.